# Is it still possible to log into Stack Exchange using an AOL OpenID?

Tags: support, bug, user-accounts, openid, authentication

I am posting from a new account I have created, as I have been unable to access my Stack Exchange account for several days.

My account is tied to my AOL OpenID exclusively. For quite some time, when signing into SE with AOL, one needed to write their AOL username *without* the `@aol.com`.

When one wrote one's username *with* the `@aol.com`, SE has historically given an error saying `canceled`. This has not been an issue, as AOL has routinely accepted AOL usernames on their OpenID authentication page without the `@aol.com` portion.

It appears to me that AOL has changed something in their authentication system, at least for some accounts. Now, AOL does not allow me to sign into my account when I omit the `@aol.com` portion, so I am forced to write `username@aol.com`.

However, with this arrangement, Stack Exchange gives me the `canceled`error (although AOL allows me to sign in). I assume this is because Stack Exchange stores my account credentials as `type: AOL, username: username (without the @aol.com)`. However, AOL will only authenticate me now with `username:username@aol.com`.

Note that AOL only seems to be doing this for OpenID authentications, rather than all logins to their system. When merely signing into my AOL account (without using their OpenID authentication system), I can access the account by merely entering my username without the `@aol.com` portion.

Is there a way to fix or circumvent this problem?

[image]

Comment: See first item in dupe: "Remove the ability to create a new account with most OpenID providers"

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Uh, "create new account" and "sign in with existing account" are *clearly* two very different things. The linked dupe indicates that there are still months to go before existing accounts can no longer be signed in to with OpenID. So a bug that prevents someone from logging into their existing account with OpenID cannot be a dupe of a plan to shut down OpenID in stages that hasn't gotten to that stage yet.

Comment: Perhaps I'd suggest to create another sign in option (perhaps using SE's own credential) with this account and request to merge with the AOL account, but the OP seems already gone...

Comment: In theory, yes, it should still be possible. In practice, as you say, it appears that something changed on AOL's end. We're deprecating support for OpenID providers in a few months, so the odds of us fixing this right now are honestly pretty slim.

Comment: @NathanTuggy huh, oops. Well, for some reason OP deleted their account. :(